# Compare Efficiently in Node.js If Two Files are Uniq

Tags: node.js, npm, diff

I'm looking for an efficient way to compare if two files are uniq in Node.js.

All I need to know is if files are equal or not. Simple `true / false` as output will be enough.

Building checksums on a files is a bit slow. Meanwhile Linux `diff` command is quite fast for comparing even large files. So i just curious if there any equivalent or module in Node.js of efficient Linux `diff` command.

---

As suggested in comments - we can try to use [stream-equal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-equal) module for that.

I just tried to compare *same* `1.3 GB` files with both `stream-equal` and `diff`

See timeframes below:

```
9.352s - stream-equal
0.008s - diff
```

Looks like `diff` is  insanely fast.

---

One way I'm thinking of speeding things up on large files is via reading first 10 bytes and last 10 bytes of the *same size* large files and compare by that. If the first and the last bytes are equal then there is quite a big chance that files are identical.

But I'm not pretty sure for now what is the correct way to implement this.

Comment: This module locks promising: [stream-equal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-equal)

Comment: Thanks Roland. I will check this out. As I see it creates streams of the files. How efficient it will be on large files sizes? Lets say few GB files.

Comment: it looks efficient for files with some GB, the code base looks simple, try running some tests before actually implementing the package. If you are using streams you can pause and close the stream as soon as you find an difference between and avoid any further processing because you have an clue that the file are different.

Comment: As i understand it, it will fail at the first byte that is different and then stop reading. so if most of your files differ in the begining it should be pretty fast.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks @RolandStarke and Gntem. To speed things up on large files - is there anyway we can read lets say first 10 bytes and last 10 bytes of the files and compare by that? If first and last bytes are equal the files are identical. Or there is no way to access last bytes of a file without reading all bytes before them?

Comment: I just gave a try stream-equal. Will update my question with results.

Comment: Can you just use child_process to run diff under the hood, or are you trying for cross-platform?  Odds are good you'll have a hard time matching natively compiled C programs in Node no matter what you do.

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestion @Paul. I am trying to do this cross-platform. As I noticed  Windows has `diff` equivalent `fc`. But I would really like to avoid `child_process` if possible, since app will not be compliant with App Stores because of calling command line. Thanks again!